# Problems with pynput when reading a list from a pickle file

Tags: linux, python-3.x, pickle, pynput

i made a keylistener programm  with pynput that appended the keys that were pressed to a list that i saved in a pickle file but when i loaded the file the outputs are different

```
import pynput
from pynput.keyboard import Key,Controller
import pickle
keyboard = Controller()
with open("hahahahhahah", 'rb') as f:
    l = pickle.load(f)
print(type(l[1]))
#outputs:^<class 'pynput.keyboard._xorg.KeyCode'>



print(l)
#^outputs:['d', 's', 'a', 'f', 's', 'd', 'f',]
print(l[2])
#^outputs:'a'
keyboard.press(l[1])
keyboard.release(l[1])
keyboard.press(l[1])
keyboard.release(l[1])
keyboard.press(l[1])
keyboard.release(l[1])
keyboard.press(l[1])
keyboard.release(l[1])
keyboard.press(l[1])
keyboard.release(l[1])
```

this just outputs # 5 times when i wanted it to output s 5 times

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's expected that posters will have tried to solve the problem themselves before posting here. Can you explain what you've tried already?

Comment: I tried pyautogui to type the keycodes instead of pyput but that didnt work. I think the problem is the keycode datatype the letters are but i dont know how to change that.

Comment: i have found the error and i solved it by changing the code that was getting the keys beause for some reason pynput cant read pynputkeycode if it has been loaded from a file the so i had to change the datatype it threw me off a bit because if i imported the script directly into the code above id work like normal. i had to change    `k+=[key] `  to     `k+=[key.char]`and put i inside a try and xcept